# Variable is not being echoed

Tags: linux, bash

When I run the following script in Bash 3.2.48:

```
#!/bin/bash

export var1='var1'
echo "UID=$UID"

if [ x"$UID" != x"0" ]
then
    export var2='var2'
    while ! { sudo -v; }; do { sudo -v; }; done;
    sudo $0
    exit
fi

echo $var1
echo $var2

exit 0
```

What I get as output is:

```
UID=1000
UID=0
var1
```

Why is var2 not exported and echoed? I'm pretty sure that the same script worked with older Bash versions.

Answer (score 5):

- you enter first time with UID == 1000, you enter the if clause
- you sudo to execute the script with UID == 0; 
  sudo **doesn't preserve the environment** if env_reset is set in /etc/sudoers (default in most distros). You need **sudo -E** to preserve env.
- you exit (**before echoing**)

from the sudo call you enter with clean env.

- you enter with UID == 0
- **you don't enter the if clause, var2 is not set**
- you echo the variables.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is much more simpler than is seems: you **never** echo those vars (when **not** running as root, obviously), because you already exit :))

Try avoiding/minimizing confusion by adding more appropriate/concise debug statements. For instance, use a single echo that contains **everything** that's relevant to your problem (i.e. process ID, user ID, var1, var2):

```
#!/bin/bash
export var1='var1'
if [ "$UID" != "0" ] ; then
    export var2='var2'
    while ! { sudo -v; }; do { sudo -v; }; done;
    sudo $0
    # this is "the key exit" ;-)
    #exit
fi
echo "pid=[$$] uid=[$UID] var1=[$var1] var2=[$var2]"
```

With the exit commented out you get what you expect (obviously, in the "parent" process, as the "child" one - the one running as "root" - never reaches that part of the code that exports var2):

```
pid=[12346] uid=[0] var1=[var1] var2=[]
pid=[12345] uid=[1] var1=[var1] var2=[var2]
```

++ sometimes running scripts in *debug mode* (bash -x) helps too ;-)

Comment: Thank you altblue, I really appreciate your help. But no, that is not what I want. Of cource this is only a sample code, the real script is much longer and the part after the if-clause should only be executed once, after re-calling the script with 'sudo $0'. But I see the point with sudo now, it really works with 'sudo -E $0', since var2 is exported then. The strange thing is, that this worked on my old system without the -E switch or modifying the sudoers file. Anyway, I'm happy now. Thank you guys.
Chris